# AWS CDK pipelines cross account source with codestar connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

Looking to setup the source for my pipeline to be triggered from a codestar connection on a different AWS account.

How can I use the CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction to connect to a cross account arn:aws:codestar-connections resource?

The other account has the resource arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-west-2:connection/aEXAMPLE-8aad-4d5d-8878-dfcab0bc441f. It's all wired up and works.

I create a policy of:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "codestar-connections:PassConnection"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-west-2:connection/aEXAMPLE-8aad-4d5d-8878-dfcab0bc441f",
        "Condition": {"ForAllValues:StringEquals": {"codestar-connections:PassedToService": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"}}
    }
}
```

And allow a trusted account to assume that role.

Then I add:

```
const role = new iam.Role.fromARN("Role that allows assuming above policy from cross account");
const sourceAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction({
  connectionArn: "arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-west-2:connection/aEXAMPLE-8aad-4d5d-8878-dfcab0bc441f",
  role: role,
})
```

Then CodePipeline assumes that role so it can use that codestar connection? It fails to work that way because it tries to mutate the cross account role that's in the other account. Then if I out mutable false it losses permission to bucket.

Comment: Did you try adding the S3 permissions to that sourceAction? 
Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I was! I'm on mobile but I'll get solution to you. Tldr is add s3 and kms perms in addition to codestar use connection to the role. Then in kms and s3 add the resource based policies. Source action must be same region

Comment: @maletor would it be possible for you to post a more complete solution as an answer to this question? Preferably with the CloudFormation output for those of us not yet using the CDK... 